# MKS viewsegment for CLI

Tags: mks, mks-integrity

Retrieving issues from MKS server with CLI commands like *viewissue* or *issues* is okay as long as one queries a "flat" item list.

But requirements normally are hosted in a document which has a **hierarchy**. Well, the CLI therefore offers the **viewsegment** command. Unfortunately this command **only works in GUI-mode**.

> im viewsegment --gui ID

So the only way to retrieve a hierarchical structure is to do it **manually**? Read the root ID attributes and parse them for "Contains: 111111, 222222, ..." - 111111 and 222222 being sub-ID(s), e.g. subchapters in document.

Has anyone tried this before (e.g. with Perl or Python)?

Or may this even be possible with the *exportissues* command? Unfortunately the MKS manual is not very detailed on advanced query building...